# Speeding Up VB.NET application to Excel

Tags: arrays, vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2015

I have written a VB.NET application in Visual Studio 2015.  (first time ever had any contact with visual basic or VS).  The application takes an input csv file, analyses it and splits it according to that analysis into 2 output csv files.  For one of these output files, I then need to change every blank cell to have the value of zero.  My prob, is that the code i've made is processing 750 input csv files to produce 1500 output files and each process in the loop is taking 5 mins meaning it's taking up to 5 days to run!!  That is too long!

I'm trying to work out how to make the code run quicker.  One easy first step would be in the blank cell to zero operation as i'm currently doing it cell by cell.  I read that better to do via an array but i'm unsure how to code it...Can someone help?

My code now is:

```
    Dim forceDataRangeDest, cell As Excel.Range
    Dim blank As String
    Dim forceDataRow, lastDataRow As Integer

'copy force data from original workbook to sheet 1 of new workbook
            If ws.Range("Z" & (forceLegRowStart + 1)).Value = "Force Plate 3" Then
                forceDataRow = forceDataRow + 2
                forceDataRangeSrc = ws.Range("Z" & forceDataRow & ":AK" & lastDataRow)
            Else forceDataRangeSrc = ws.Range("A" & forceDataRow & ":M" & lastDataRow)
            End If
            wsData = wbForce.Sheets("Sheet1")
            wsData.Name = "Data"
            forceDataRangeDest = wsData.Range("A1")
            forceDataRangeSrc.Copy(forceDataRangeDest)

            'insert new column A if Force Plate 3 data is one taken for the time interval data of column A
            If ws.Range("Z" & (forceLegRowStart + 1)).Value = "Force Plate 3" Then
                wsData.Columns("A:A").Insert(1)
                'write in the Data
                forceDataRangeSrc = ws.Range("A" & forceDataRow & ":A" & lastDataRow)
                forceDataRangeSrc.Copy(wsData.Range("A1"))
            End If

    forceDataRangeDest = wsData.Range("A1:M" & ((lastDataRow - forceDataRow) + 1))
                For Each cell In forceDataRangeDest
                    blank = cell.Value
                    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(blank) Then
                        cell.Value = 0
                    End If
                Next
```

It is the For Each cell at the bottom of this sample code that i think is really increasing the process time...how would i write that as an array and then write array into excel in one go?

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: As you are using csv files then the fastest way would be to not use Excel but instead do all the processing in VB.NET.

Comment: If your code is working but slow I would suggest posting it on the [tag:vb.net] or [tag:excel] forum at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could use ```Range("A1:C3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0```. No searching, no loops.

Comment: I would suggest you find a library that process csv files and drop Excel, especially if you are using the interop, it's very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Range.Find` and `Range.FindNext` methods in VBA which would be quicker than looping through all the cells. Here's an example of the VBA code:

```
Sub FindEmptyCells()

Dim found As Range
Dim firstCell As String

    Set found = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(What:="", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    firstCell = found.Address

    Do While Not (found Is Nothing)
        Debug.Print found.Address
        Set found = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.FindNext(found)
        If found.Address = firstCell Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Added the code to use OP's range object

```
Dim found As Range
Dim firstCell As String

    Set found = forceDataRangeDest.Find(What:="", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    firstCell = found.Address

    Do While Not (found Is Nothing)
        found.Value = 0
        Set found = forceDataRangeDest.FindNext(found)
        If found.Address = firstCell Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: will UsedRange include cells that are null/nothing in addition to blank?

Comment: It should be the block of cells from A1 down to the last row & column that has data/formatting. It includes all cells within that block.

Comment: prob is sometimes, the last row can have data in for cells but not at the end of the row....

Comment: I read however, it's better to put the data in an array, and then manipulate the data (i.e. look for nulls or blank array elements) and THEN paste the array from A1...

Comment: It depends on effort to code vs performance required. Are you expecting lots of blank cells or just a few? You could also save as csv file (with the blank cells), read entire file into memory in VB and do string manipulation looking for ",,", etc before writing back to the file.

Comment: See [Chip Pearson's page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for guidance on using arrays and ranges.